# How many tonnes of cargo are stored on the International Space Station?

Tags: iss, spacex-starship

I think I read somewhere that SpaceX's Starship should carry 100 tonnes to the moon, and that this amount of mass was greater than the total cargo on the ISS, but I can't find a reference confirming the tonnage on the ISS.  Did I imagine it? Am I mis-remembering the quote?

Comment: What do you define as "cargo"?

Comment: Technically the answer is "non", since the ISS is not transporting things between places. But I assume, that is not what you mean. So if you want an answer, you need to answer @Steve question first.

Comment: Cargo, also known as freight, refers to goods or produce being transported from one place to another  by water, air or land. Originally, the term “cargo” referred to goods being loaded onboard a vessel. These days, however, cargo is used for all types of goods, including those carried by rail, van, truck, or intermodal container.

Comment: Though cargo means all goods onboard a transport vehicle, it does not include items such as personnel bags, goods in the storage, equipment or products to support the transport carried onboard. Cargo transport is mainly for commercial purpose for which an air waybill, bill of lading or other receipt is issued by the carrier.

Comment: https://www.saloodo.com/logistics-dictionary/cargo/